# Большем чем. Где нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Пока овощи будут продаваться в количестве(,) большем(,) чем различные продукты не природного происхождения - наше поколение будет здоровым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно предложить следующий вариант предложения: "Пока овощи будут продаваться в количестве большем, чем различные продукты неприродного происхождения, - наше поколение будет здоровым".
ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

На слово "большем" падает логическое ударение, произношение без паузы, поэтому нет запятой.

Тире - авторский знак, подчеркнутая пауза делит предложение на две части. Запятая закрывает сравнительный оборот.

Слово "наприродный" я написала бы слитно, хотя его и нет в словарях. Здесь отсутствует отрицание, определительная конструкция явно утвердительного характера.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Софией, но тире не стала бы ставить.